# How to save/map uploaded image in term field of type image with storage location equals s3://

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, media

I'm having 1 field in a taxonomy = 'features' of type image. Image storage location is set to s3.

I have written a `hook_form_alter` for form_id = article (article is the content type)  where I have created an image field like:

```
$form['image_dir'] = [
    '#type'                 => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location'      => 's3://s3-bucket',
    '#multiple'             => FALSE,
    '#description'          => t('Allowed extensions: gif png jpg jpeg'),
    '#upload_validators'    => [
      'file_validate_is_image'      => array(),
      'file_validate_extensions'    => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
      'file_validate_size'          => array(25600000)
    ],

     ];
```

Now in **my form submission**, I'm trying to **save/map** this **image** into my **term image field** (`field_vocab_image`) . For this, I'm trying something like:

```
$term = Term::create([
    'name' => $term_name,
    'vid' => 'my_vocab_name',
    'field_vocab_image' => $img,
  ]);
  $inserted = $term->save();
```

where `$img = $form_state->getvalues()['image_dir'];` this image is coming from the custom field created in `hook_form_alter`.

Above code is successfully saving term name but when I go to edit term , image field is empty. **Image is not getting mapped**.

Comment: Is `field_vocab_image` allowed to save to an external file system rather than just private or public? I'm surprised that a field validation error isn't occurring. There is also https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs, which will enable s3 storage saving for image fields.

Comment: `field_vocab_image` is already configured to store images in s3 bucket. so I go to add term page and upload image to this field, it is storing image successfully to s3 bucket. I just need to programmatically store images to this already configured s3 `field_vocab_image` field.

Answer (score -1):

An `Image` type field should contain a file `fid` of an image file. The following should resolve your issue:

```
$img = $form_state->getValue('image_dir');

if (!empty($img['fids'])) {
  $img = reset($img['fids']);
}
```